# Undefined refresh token while authorizing with OAuth2.0 in OneDrive for business

Tags: java, rest, curl

While authorizing with Oauth 2.0 in OneDrive for Business, I am getting `refresh_token` as `undefined`. Is there any specific reason for getting this?

I'm using this endpoint:

```
curl https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token
```

Comment: are you getting a valid `access_token`? Probably, you're not allowed to get a new token from the refresh one, or their service doesn't support token refreshing

Comment: am getting a valid access_token, am able to do file operations with that token but refresh_token is undefined.